# Linear equations and the gcd

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

given integers $a$ & $b$ it can be shown that the equation: $$ax + by = gcd(a,b)$$ always has a solution.  To prove this we assume the exitence of two solutions $$(x_1, y_1)$$ & $$(x_2, y_2)$$  Using the Euclidean algorithm we can arrive at a general solution: $$(x_1 + k(\frac{b}{g}), y_1 - k(\frac{a}{g})$$ where $g = gcd(a,b)$ and $k = x_2y_1 - x_1y_2$

This is where my issue is.  In the explanation they state that we find that $$x_2 = x_1 + kb$$ and a similar thing for $y_2$. But how is this possible if $x_2$ and $y_2$ are both contained in $k$?  I get the idea that a difference of integers would still be an integer,  but we are using the same variable we are trying to find in our solution. I am having an issue reconciling this.

Comment: I don't think you're reading your source correctly. One can't prove that an equation has solutions by assuming the existence of two solutions. Perhaps you're reading a proof of the characterization of all solutions? I also don't know what you mean by "$x_2$ and $y_2$ are both contained in $k$", since $k$ is a number.

Comment: you're right.  it is a "characterization" of all solutions. So that would mean I would have to manually churn out two sets of solutions in order for this pricedure to apply in theory? I know I don't have to because the proxedure is explained,  but if for instance I had not known the procedure beforehand.  The text is Silverman's Number Theory